# How can I limit a post's taxonomy term selection to only one per level?

Tags: wordpress

**What is possible now:**

A user can select multiple terms

[image]

---

**Desired behaviour:**

A user can select only on term per level. (Only **one term** on the first level and only **one term** on the second level)

[image]

---

I use custom taxonomies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can limit your user with some js that you can add only on admin area using [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/)

And then some code:

```
    jQuery('.cat-checklist input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(event){
        var checked = jQuery(this).prop('checked');
        // Clear all other inputs on this level:
        jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        // Set the value:
    jQuery(this).prop('checked', checked)
})
```

Tested on the quick edit screen but you've got the idea.

From the other side, you can also modify the saved data for example using the [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook. You'll be able to get the list of taxonomies that are going to be saved and then limit them.

Comment: This only works on a second level for me 

Comment: @zappefi the code is updated to work on any level